# .NET MAUI tap-able paths forming an image

Tags: xaml, svg, maui

I'm quite new to .net maui, I'm trying to achieve an image (suppose a car) made of Paths, where each `Path` is a body part and it should be tap-able.
I managed to recreate the "image" using the same paths I've used in the html/svg version, the problem is each Path occupies the whole row/column area, so they're all piled up, and no matter where I tap only the Path on top responds to the tap event.
In the code sample below no matter where I tap the screen only the "Roof" path is being clicked.

Here's a sample of the XAML code I used:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, *" ColumnDefinitions="*">
    <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}" Grid.Row="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M28.9661 92.8987C27.63 92.1352 24.8478 90.0315 20.0117 83.1594 18.93 81.4414 18.2868 81.5505 18.103 78.578 19.6121 79.0359 19.0634 76.5668 18.8329 75.3758 17.1239 66.7799 17.5058 58.3168 18.9695 49.8541 19.2093 48.2953 19.4054 47.2461 18.1476 47.4511 18.2214 46.383 18.2951 45.315 18.3689 44.2469 20.2142 43.4833 24.1811 36.3218 28.462 33.487 33.1073 30.5598 67.9821 27.8926 69.4637 29.0631 72.4913 30.8617 71.8777 31.3126 72.774 32.3369 62.593 39.979 61.7622 84.6094 72.6824 93.6304 72.1717 95.4438 70.2626 96.8439 68.8628 97.2255 55.1821 96.8439 43.7923 95.953 31.1295 93.3442Z" />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.82" ScaleY="1.76" />
                <TranslateTransform X="106" Y="18" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
        <Path.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                Command="{Binding ChangePartStatusCommand }"
                CommandParameter="Hood" />
        </Path.GestureRecognizers>
    </Path>

    <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding AnotherViewModelProperty}" Grid.Row="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M74.8111 31.612C82.1595 33.617 90.6173 35.1439 98.4878 36.906 99.822 37.3776 99.6194 37.6815 99.4277 38.903 97.4761 52.3736 96.2167 65.9125 99.434 86.3484 99.4541 86.8021 99.9942 87.5787 99.0489 87.9837 91.0473 89.6718 82.7757 91.4274 74.8416 93.4533 75.1446 94.0957 76.09 94.9059 76.9679 95.1423 84.9023 93.385 91.3845 91.1906 99.7236 89.7066 107.4212 88.3881 118.2925 87.7131 124.7072 87.5779 136.5916 87.1738 145.6735 87.7478 152.6963 88.624 161.3741 89.673 168.2612 92.1039 171.5362 93.2857 174.9685 91.7439 179.2335 91.1585 181.8332 88.6602 174.7775 87.7145 167.631 86.5666 160.53 85.5198 159.8363 85.3749 159.601 84.7776 159.7637 84.2889 162.8957 69.5402 162.4259 54.1516 159.8415 41.4647 159.5439 40.5871 159.7129 39.8105 160.3879 39.743 167.6806 38.2911 174.5342 37.4134 181.7594 36.5355 178.3384 34.9825 175.8518 32.7204 171.4966 31.8763 165.2167 34.476 157.823 35.6914 151.7119 36.6368 147.0866 37.447 136.5865 38.021 124.4662 37.4809 103.7775 36.9126 96.3161 34.7182 76.7472 30.006Z" />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.8" ScaleY="1.77" />
                <TranslateTransform X="4" Y="15" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
        <Path.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                Command="{Binding ChangePartStatusCommand }"
                CommandParameter="Roof" />
        </Path.GestureRecognizers>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

I've also tried to use buttons clipping them with the same paths `<Button Clip="M28.9661 92.8987C27.63...">` but the result is identical.

Is there anyone who can kindly help me achieve this?

Comment: There is no such functionality in Maui. Nor in SkiaSharp. Nor built in to Windows, iOS, or android OS.  With a TapGestureRecognizer you can get (x,y) within a rectangular View. From there, you would need some c# library with math that would help calculate whether a given (x,y) falls within a given polygon. Recommending a library is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. And even with a library, its a major project. Maybe ask on `computergraphics stackexchange` site.